# A construction of abstract Wiener spaces using Prokhorov's theorem

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am struggling with [Leonard Gross's (original) construction of abstract Wiener spaces (AWS)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200513262). His proof is somewhat convoluted, but from what I have been able to understand he constructs a certain compact subset $C _\varepsilon$ that he transports in some finite-dimensional spaces $K$, an idea reminding me of Prokorov's theorem (the one giving a necessary and sufficient condition for a promeasure to be generated by a measure). This makes me ask:

> is there a more straightforward construction of AWS, based directly and explicitly upon Prokhorov's theorem?

I do know of an alternative construction of AWS, namely the one in Bogachev's "Gaussian Measures", but it is based upon Fernique's theorem, therefore not exactly what I want.

Comment: I don't think I've seen one but it ought to be fairly straightforward.  Can you quote the precise version of Prokhorov you would like to use?

Comment: Specifically, I'm not immediately finding a version of the theorem in the context of an arbitrary separable Banach space, which is where we'd need to work to get Gross's theorem.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The idea is to take the closure of the space $H$ in a new norm, thus embedding $H$ in some Banach space $B$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ construct a compact set $C_\epsilon \subset B$. Then apply Prokhorov: the promeasure $(P_i)_{i \in I}$ is generated by a measure on $B$ iff $P_i (X_i \setminus p_i (C_\epsilon)) < \epsilon$, where $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is a projective system with connecting maps $p_{ij} : X_j \to X_i$ and $p_i : B \to X_i$ are the natural projections. The $X_i$ are the finite-dimensional subspaces of $H$. $(P_i)_{i \in I}$ is the promeasure on $(X_i)_{i \in I}$.

Comment: What's the "natural projection" $p_i$ here?  $B$ is only a Banach space, not generally a Hilbert space, so orthogonal projection isn't available.  Also, do you have a reference for this version of the theorem?

Comment: By the way, in case you're interested, there is an alternative proof in [these lecture notes of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03591), see Theorem 4.44.  Maybe you'll find it less "convoluted".  It doesn't need Fernique, and the main convergence tool is just the Borel-Cantelli lemma.